# Robot Rigging: Join + Parent Bone or Parent to Empty Group

Tags: rigging, bones

For robot/mecha rigging, is it better to rig by:

1. Join objects, and parent bone to the armature?
   OR
2. Parent with Empty group, and assign each bone to armature?

If both methods are viable, then what is the major difference between these two methods?

Thanks

Comment: i personally would use objects and parent to bone. I have no idea why you want to join first, because this would make things complicated, wouldn't it?

Comment: Depends on what kind of tweaks you might want to do down the road, but I would join first.

Comment: imho it's more convenient to have one unique object so I would lean towards solution #2

Comment: For complex mech designs, will people join object? or do parent with empty groups? When I was looking through tutorials - there was mix between two methods, so I wasn't sure which methods to follow;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a single right answer to which is better.

Usually, visually, the two models are going to be identical, whether they're armature deformed from single assigned groups or bone parented.  (Depending on whether you're doing anything weird.)

In Blender, the bone parented parts are going to be more performant than the armature deformed parts-- potentially much, much more performant, if there are a lot of vertices, a lot of bones, or live modifiers.  For example, a subdivision doesn't need to be recalculated on an object transformation, but it does get recalculated on armature deformation, even if it ends up being the same in both cases; and when a subdivision is recalculated, it gets recalculated on the whole object, so there's a big difference between that object being one piston and that object being a whole robot with fifty pistons.

In other animation engines, this is not necessarily the case.  Game engines use more highly tuned armature deformation algorithms, and might even use a specific single-bone algorithm for when that's appropriate, leading to performance about equal to object transformation (but perhaps done on CPU rather than GPU, so it's kind of apples-to-oranges); meanwhile, each object requires its own draw call, enough of which can bottleneck performance.  In a game engine, I would generally expect the single armature-deformed object to be more performant, but it can depend on a lot of variables.

Beyond performance, there are usage issues.  There *is* something nice about creating objects such that a single, discrete, conceptual thing is also a single, discrete object in the interface.  While multiple objects can be organized together via collections or parenting, it is easier to animate a shapekey on a single object than on a collection of objects, it is easier to adjust UV or vertex groups (which may be used for more than just deformation) on a single object, it is easier to change modifier parameters, and armature-deformed objects can be separated and rejoined without losing important parenting information (because they're all parented to the same armature, rather than to individual bones in that armature.)

There are also potential issues related to object space.  Armature deformation does not change the space of an object; the object space typically aligns with world space.  Bone parenting *does*.  This primarily affects materials that use object coordinates, but it can also affect modifiers (displace in local +Z, for example), and especially, can affect geometry nodes, where object space is very convenient and other spaces are very inconvenient.  This is a situation where, again, there is no right answer-- sometimes you want your GN acting in the space of the world and sometimes you want them acting in the space of the bone-- but bone parenting *tends* to win out here for how people like to work.  For example, object coordinates can be convenient to use for an eyeball, and those would have to baked to UV textures if you wanted to armature deform, but not if you wanted to bone parent.

Comment: I think this answer is a good quick overview without getting too much into detail - usually I would have said the question is asking for opinion-based answers. But at least this hints at what one has to think about when creating these rigs.